# MulterError: Unexpected field

Tags: mongodb, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

i,m trying to upload the image using multer and multer gridfs but it,s giving me this error...please have a look and suggest me a fix...thanks in advance.

[MulterError: Unexpected field][1]
at wrappedFileFilter (/home/atul/Documents/coding/project and practice/fb-clone-backend/node_modules/multer/index.js:40:19)
at Busboy. (/home/atul/Documents/coding/project and practice/fb-clone-backend/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:114:7)
at Busboy.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Busboy.emit (/home

```js
//imports
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import multer from 'multer';
import GridFsStorage from 'multer-gridfs-storage';
import Grid from 'gridfs-stream';
// import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import path from 'path';
import Pusher from 'pusher';
// import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;

//app config
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

//middlewares
app.use(express.json()); //Used to parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //Parse URL-encoded bodies
app.use(cors());
//db config
const mongoURI =
    'mongodb+srv://admin:atul1210@cluster0.avlrm.mongodb.net/fbdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

mongoose
    .connect(mongoURI, {
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('connection successful...');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('connection failed...');
    });

mongoose.connection.once('open', () => console.log('DB COnnected'));

var gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
    console.log('DB Connected');

    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('images');
});

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: mongoURI,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            {
                const filename = `image-${Date.now()}${path.extname(
                    file.originalname
                )}`;

                const fileInfo = {
                    filename: filename,
                    bucketName: 'images',
                };
                resolve(fileInfo);
            }
        });
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
// console.log({ storage });

//api routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.status(200).send('hello world'));

app.post('/upload/image', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log('>>>>>', req.file);

    res.status(201).send(req.file);
});

// listen
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on localhost ${port}`));
```

/atul/Documents/coding/project and practice/fb-clone-backend/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:38:33)
at PartStream. (/home/atul/Documents/coding/project and practice/fb-clone-backend/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:213:13)
at PartStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
at HeaderParser. (/home/atul/Documents/coding/project and practice/fb-clone-backend/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:51:16)
at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:315:20)
at HeaderParser._finish (/home/atul/Documents/coding/project and practice/fb-clone-backend/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:68:8)
at SBMH. (/home/atul/Documents/coding/project and practice/fb-clone-backend/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:40:12)
at SBMH.emit (events.js:315:20)
at SBMH._sbmh_feed (/home/atul/Documents/coding/project and practice/fb-clone-backend/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:159:14)
at SBMH.push (/home/atul/Documents/coding/project and practice/fb-clone-backend/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:56:14)
at HeaderParser.push (/home/atul/Documents/coding/project and practice/fb-clone-backend/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:46:19)
at Dicer._oninfo (/home/atul/Documents/coding/project and practice/fb-clone-backend/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:197:25)
at SBMH. (/home/atul/Documents/coding/project and practice/fb-clone-backend/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:127:10)

Comment: Check the name of the file. It has to be “file” in the upload form for the that particular input.

Comment: actually i am using postman to test it...i haven't made any other file yet..